# Stable subspaces of $\mathbb{P}_n$ using derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If we take a vector space $V\subset \mathbb{P}_n$ (polynomials of degree less or iqual to $n$), I want to prove that if $V$ is stable by derivation then $V=\mathbb{P}_r$ for some $r\leq n$, i.e. if $V=\langle p_1,\dots, p_r\rangle$ and $\langle p_1',\dots, p_r'\rangle \subset \langle p_1,\dots, p_r\rangle$ then $V=\mathbb{P_r}$.

This is my conjecture, perhaps there are other spaces satisfying this condition. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the highest-degree polynomial of V. if f is such a polynomial of grau r, than derivative r times you check that $$a_r \in V$$ implies that $$1 \in V$$, if you derivative r-1 times you check that $$a_{r-1}+a_rx \in V$$ thus $$x \in V$$ analogously you concluded that $$1,x,x^2,...,x^r \in V$$ thus $$V=\mathbb{P}_r$$

Note that $$x^k$$ with $k>r$ is not belongs to $$V$$ for maximality
 of $$f$$.

Comment: What if some $a_i$ is 0 for $f$?

Comment: Okay, but there's always a V-polynomial, whose $$ a_j $$ are not null, I've taken the higher degree, but if you do what you said, you can always take another polynomial to ensure this.